# How to use gdb to trace all static global variables that are initialized before main()

Tags: c++, gdb, global-variables

Currently I work in a C++ project which uses lots of static global objects. Some of them are not very well handled and have dependencies which will cause run time error. In order to resolve these issues, I want to check all the static global objects usage in our code. So how can I get find the static global objedts with GDB? We also use lots of third party code/lib so the simple "grep" may cause more time.

Comment: To get access of symbols within third party code, their lib should be build with -g option, else you may not have an access to the the variables defined in their lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `info variables` to get the information of variables defined including static variables.

Comment: Thanks this is what I need. Is there any filter we can set? So far I can see it prints out ten thousands of variables before I reach main().

Comment: If you define a scope and put a break point within the scope, you may try 'info locals'